# set dots at the end of UIButton if title is long

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton, I want to set title for it with a long text. e.g: @"set dots at the end of UIButton if title is long"

I used:

```
[btn setTitle:@"set dots at the end of UIButton if title is long" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

--> btn appear as: "set dots...at the"

Now I want to show "set dots at the..."

How I can do?

Thanks All!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLineBreakMode

Comment: NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail

The line is displayed so that the beginning fits in the container and the missing text at the end of the line is indicated by an ellipsis glyph.

Answer (score 22):

Surprisingly, there is no existing post about this for a button label.

Simply do:

```
[btn setTitle:@"set dots at the end of UIButton if title is long" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

Accessing the button's `titleLabel` lets you adjust the button's label attributes as needed when a direct `UIButton` method doesn't exist.

Comment: yes @rmaddy, I did as the same, and it works well :) thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In storyboard after select button go to attribute inspector and set lineBreak property to Truncate Tail.

.[image]